# unescape text encoded in php, in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some server side code in `PHP` which looks like this

```
$var2 = htmlspecialchars($var1);
```

For example,

```
"It's Monday" gets converted to "It&#039;s Monday"
```

I am not able to decode the text back in javascript using the function [unescape.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp)

```
unescape("It&#039;s Monday") // returns "It&#039;s Monday"
```

How can i decode this in javascript to get the original string back, apart from using [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) (because this way i'd have to manually handle all special cases) ?

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars` in the first place? `unescape` doesn't work, since you haven't escaped anything.

Comment: My php code renders a page, javascript handles the client side code. Thus using `htmlspecialchars` and not escape.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi That doesn't really explain the use of `htmlspecialchars`. What you're doing is not uncommon, yet I've never had to use `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @kba My `PHP` code embeds a `JSON` string (which is encoded using `htmlspecialchars`) in the HTML DOM, which is used by my `Javascript` code. Is there any other alternative to this approach ?

Comment: Why are you encoding your JSON with `htmlspecialchars`? I don't see a reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the html-encoded text to an dummy element and get back it's *text*, to do this:

```
$('<span/>').html("It&#039;s Monday").text()
```

returns `"It's Monday"`

*Note:* The above does *not* modify the DOM (unlike I said before I edited the answer)

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like a hack (might get stuck in my code review :p), is there any other way ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi - This is indeed a hacky way of doing it. The *right* way will involve capturing `&.+;` in the string and replacing with the appropriate character (probably using a table of characters).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to encode your text using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) in PHP if you want to decode it again using JavaScript's [`unescape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp).

```
// PHP
urlencode("It's Monday") // returns "It%27s%20Monday"

// JavaScript
unescape("It%27s%20Monday") // returns "It's Monday"
```